# Escaping quotes while enqueuing scripts

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

Have a quick question,

Below code is a simple function for enqueue the scripts in WordPress, but the problem is with JS, not PHP. At this state it gives an error:

> Missing ) after argument list

I believe it is a problem with my method of escaping the quotes, since using this script manually by adding to the footer works OK.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    wp_enqueue_style('sage/main.css', asset_path('styles/main.css'), false, null);
    wp_enqueue_script('sage/main.js', asset_path('scripts/main.js'), ['jquery'], null, true);
    $inline_js = 'var $zoho=$zoho || {};$zoho.salesiq = $zoho.salesiq || {widgetcode:"a7d50e2c5dd79539b3393dbeaf47ed569e663414dbe68c618856655be9267b02", values:{},ready:function(){}};
var d=document;s=d.createElement("script");s.type="text/javascript";s.id="zsiqscript";s.defer=true;
s.src="https://salesiq.zoho.com/widget";t=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];t.parentNode.insertBefore(s,t);d.write("<div id=\'zsiqwidget\'></div>")';
    wp_add_inline_script('sage/main.js', $inline_js);
}, 100);
```

What I am missing here?
Big thanks for the help!

Comment: In PHP anything within single quotes is taken literally. I'd try changing it to `$inline_js = "var ...` and escaping the double quotes instead of the single quotes.

Comment: What is `$zoho`? Is that a PHP variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using dollar sign in conjunction with some other variables, I assume you are trying to get a php variable inside your inline script. You will have 3 options.

### Closing and opening the quotes

You can `echo` a variable in this way:

```
echo 'Hello' . $world;
```

### Using double quotes

The same above code can be written in this way:

```
echo "Hello $world";
```

Pay attention to the double quotes.

### Using curved brackets & double quotes

This is the cleanest way to do it, since it makes reading the code much easier:

```
echo "Hello {$world}";
```

So, your code can be turned into this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {

    wp_enqueue_style('sage/main.css', asset_path('styles/main.css'), false, null);
    wp_enqueue_script('sage/main.js', asset_path('scripts/main.js'), ['jquery'], null, true);

    $inline_js = "
    var {$zoho} = {$zoho} || {};
    {$zoho}.salesiq = {$zoho}.salesiq || {
        widgetcode:'a7d50e2c5dd79539b3393dbeaf47ed569e663414dbe68c618856655be9267b02', 
        values:{},
        ready:function(){}
    };
    var d=document;
    s=d.createElement('script');
    s.type='text/javascript';
    s.id='zsiqscript';
    s.defer=true;
    s.src='https://salesiq.zoho.com/widget';
    t=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    t.parentNode.insertBefore(s,t);
    d.write('<div id=\'zsiqwidget\'></div>')";

   wp_add_inline_script('sage/main.js', $inline_js);
}, 100);
```

I also formatted the code so it's easier to be read.

Comment: Only works for PHP variables, stripslashes on javascript like `$('button[class*="-wp-"]')` needs to be escaped the old way.